# React :: Sections are turning white while Scrolling Up and Down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

Do you guys have any quick solution to this?

I'm scrolling up and down really fast and you can see some portions are turning white. Please refer to my short recording below:
https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cYjuXRmdje

I'm using Chrome browser and did some research about and it seems its because of the new issue in Chrome. **Hardware acceleration**, it can be found in **Chrome Settings > Advanced > System > "Use hardware acceleration when available"**

Turning it off works but how about in Edge or something similar.

Live Site: https://hitchcliff.github.io/onepage-studio/
Github Repository: https://github.com/hitchcliff/onepage-studio-code

Comment: Are you using any onScroll event handlers? My guess is you have some time-consuming JS that is running as you are scrolling that is preventing the browser from updating effectively (edit: from a quick look at the repo I couldn't see much)

Comment: Maybe adding little snippet of your code in would help us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suspicion was it would be some JS running that would prevent the browser from updating, after using the chrome dev tools I couldn't see anything obvious.

I then looked at the images you have on the page and they are HUGE, you have some images that are over 10mb! Ideally (and this depends on the context) you should get your images below 100kb (and preferably smaller!).

I would suggest you run all your images through a tool like: https://squoosh.app/ or https://tinypng.com/ - I suspect this will solve your issue. It will take a lot of effort for the browser to process files this big, hence why you are seeing white areas.

In the long term, consider introducing a minification tool as part of your build process to help automate stuff like this.

Comment: Actually, there is no time-consuming JS code since this is just a basic one page layout and as far as I can remember. 

I did some testing every section and component to see if the problem will occur. But that didn't happen when there are only a few sections of the page. So I just drop suspicion in image sizes.

I will have to check those suggestions, thank you!

Comment: You are right, it was because of the image sizes!!!

However, my hunch was right that it was because of "Hardware Acceleration in Chrome".  It is now working smoothly in Edge. 

I notice something odd as well, it is showing white screen, even though I'm still in development (local).